# Embedded apps having GPIO, SPI Android

Tags: android, sdk, embedded

I am working on the android application having the GPI0 classes or function used. I am new to using embedded app.

I have an existing code for that but i am unable to find these import

import android.gpio.GPIO;

import android.gpio.GPIOException;

and functions to hardware interface on i.Mx53

i am not understand from where i can import these classes. i am getting importing errors and there is no native library in libs folder also.

Is there any supported libray for using these in android sdk or i have to installed other sdk or supported library.

please provide me some tutorial or help on this.

Comment: There are no such classes in Android, and especially not in its SDK.  It is possible that someone created a custom fork from Android which adds them to the platform, but you would have to contact them for that.  If they had been reasonable and put them in *their own* namespace, you would know who to talk to.

Comment: Thanks Chris...i think so that would be help for me to contact with developers.